# Node.js Nodemailer And SES - Error: No transport method defined

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send emails with SES. I am setting it up like this:

```
require("nodemailer").createTransport("SES", {
    AWSAccessKeyID: "AKIAJZFUSYQJNEX3VS2A",
    AWSSecretKey: "XXX", //real information removed
    SeviceUrl:"https://email.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
}),
```

When I Send The Email I Get:

> Error: No transport method defined

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

*EDIT:*Tried Both solutions, and they did not work

Answer (score 4):

You have to use your transport on sending mail. Just try as follows,

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SES", {
    AWSAccessKeyID: "AKIAJZFUSYQJNEX3VS2A",
    AWSSecretKey: "XXX",
    SeviceUrl:"https://email.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
}),

//On sending mail
nodemailer.sendMail({
        transport : transport, //pass your transport
        sender : 'senderid@email.com' ,
        to : 'receiverid@email.com',
        subject : "SUBJECT",
        html: '<p> Hello World </p>'
      })
```

Note: Here I assume, your transport is valid one and your key is enough permission(Network permission as well.)

Answer (score 3):

Your `ServiceUrl` is configured incorrectly. Amazon SES is only [available in us-east-1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) at this time. Please set `ServiceUrl` to `https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

Also, for future reference, please do not share your AWS Secret Key. I strongly recommend that you rotate your AWS keys since they were posted earlier in your question.

Comment: Thanks About The Keys, Just Changed Them